# Сравнение введённого слова и слова в файле

Tags: python, файлы

Есть файл в нём три слова:
`help`
`hi`
`hell`
введены через ряд каждое.
Когда я сравниваю введённое пользователем слово со словом в файле, то на первом срабатывает, а второе как будто игнорируется
Код python:

```py
with open('yarin.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as r:
    x = r.readlines()
    n = input("Name:")
    i = 0
    da = 'yes'
    ne = 'no'
    read = x[i].strip()
    while read != n:
        i += 1
        if i == 10:
            print(ne)
            break
        else:
            pass
    else:
        if read == n:
           print(da)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: тут такая элементарная причина, что ее можно самостоятельно найти в отладчике. Подсказка: чему равно i в ``read = x[i].strip()``

Comment: @Эникейщик ну вот я вижу то что `i  = 0` и перед read у меня это указано, может я просто что-то не понимаю? Первая строка всегда 0

Comment: Ну так первая строка и обрабатывается. А остальные нет, потому что i всегда равно 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед циклом ты ставишь `read` как первую строку, а в самом цикле не обновляешь переменную (`i` меняется, но `read` нет)

Answer (score -2):

Всё что нужно было сделать код понятнее и легче, а так же как не странно просто на словах обьяснить сложно но вот код:

```py
import re
op = len(re.findall(r"[\n']+", open('yarin.txt').read())) #узнаём кол-во строк
op -= 1 #отнимаем 1 так как счёт начинается с 0
with open('yarin.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as r:
    x = r.readlines()
    name = input('name:')
    nick = x[op].strip() 
    while name != nick:
        nick = x[op].strip() #если не указать число останется 2
        op -= 1
        nick = x[op].strip() #так же как и выше
        if op < 0 and name != nick:
            print('Неверно введено имя!')
            break
    else:
        print('Имя введено верно!')
```

Comment: чет легче для понимания совсем не стало..

Comment: В таком случае сделайте код полегче и ещё понятнее для вас. Я просто не сильно стремлюсь к лёгкости, а то что вы не поняли ну извините для меня к примеру тут всё понятно, больше дополнять не буду, а если нужно полностью обьяснить то без проблем

Comment: вы пишете в ответе, что "все что нужно было сделать код понятнее". при этом конструкции которые вы используете усложняют читабельность кода, имена переменных не несут никакого смыслового значения, комментарии излишни, не несут никакой смысловой нагрузки. мне ничего объяснять не надо. и дополнять тоже. ответ на ваш же вопрос